# Hosting Audio Files

Tags: audio, architecture, amazon-s3, hosting, audio-streaming

I'm considering building a website that helps musicians collaborate remotely. To do this, they would need to share large (uncompressed) audio files.

For the solution I'm considering, I'd like to be able to perform the following functions:

- upload/download uncompressed audio files
- stream uploaded audio

My concern is the large bandwidth demand. Should I perform these actions on my own (hosted) server space, or is there a service with APIs I can use?

I've checked out Amazon's S3 which allows me to host files, however I can't find anything that suggests I can stream from their services. I'm not sure that S3 is right for what I'm trying to achieve.

Can someone provide some high-level architectural advice?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Amazon S3 keeps your data on some of their disks, but isn't intended as a high volume, low latency content delivery network (CDN).  Cloudfront is Amazon's CDN that keeps multiple copies of your data on disks that are "near" customers around the world.  Cloudfront accepts data from S3 and has various streaming solutions.  See http://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/streaming/

Answer (score 2):

What Paul mentioned in his comments is true... S3 is not designed to be a CDN.

However, if your audio files aren't intended to be used by over a thousand people at a time, you don't actually need a CDN.  You can put them on S3 and stream directly from there (over HTTP) without difficulty.  It sounds like you're going to have a bunch of tracks that will only be accessed by a handful of people.  S3 is fine for this.

When it comes to publishing finished work that might be used by many, that would be a good time to use Cloudfront.